# Is there any guide lines for AirPlay on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, sdk, airplay

I there any guide line for AirPlay on iOS?

Any sample code and tutorial is well cone.

The only thing I could find is in [What's New in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4_3.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010567-SW2) from apple.

Comment: allowsAirPlay=YES; property supported in ios 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *MPMoviePlayerController* gets a new boolean property `allowsAirPlay` which you can use to set the availablity of this feature in your app.